# HTC EVO with Evernote App - pictures upside down

Tags: camera, photos, evernote

I'm trying to use the Evernote app to take a photo and upload it.
I create a note, take a picture of a business card.  I'm holding the camera sideways, aiming down at the card on the table in front of me.  When I see the note in the Evernote app on the EVO or on Evernote site, the business card is upside down.

I've even tried rotating the pictures in the gallery and attaching them, but they always come out upside down.

I'm new to the phone, so could be I'm doing some really wrong. Or maybe Evernote has a limitation for the "free users"?

Update: I just uploaded pics to my PC, and they were upside down there to.  So the rotate/orientation on the EVO must own be for display there, not in the actual photo-file itself?

I'll try flipping the camera the other way... seems like I tried that last night, but will try again.

Answer (score 2):

Try turning the camera 180 degrees.  Clearly Evernote is confused about where the top and bottom are.

Also, I have found when editing in the gallery then uploading to Evernote, if I only rotated the picture the edits don't seem to take. It does work however if I rotate it, then crop it (I don't really crop anything out, but just go through the motions) and save it.  On those photos, Evernote recognizes the edits.

Comment: Like I said in the post, "I tried flipping the camera the other way" i.e. 180 and 90 as well. I tried some the next day, and they worked okay, just looking for rules and consistency.